# Treemap ignoring my override of the equals function

Tags: java, treemap

I have a TreeMap where RobotKey is a class consisting of a string field domain, and a long field timestamp. RobotKey implements comparable as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this.domain.equals(((RobotKey) obj).getDomain()))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

And the treemap is sort according to the following compareTo function:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(RobotKey arg0) {
    if (this.lastAccessed < arg0.lastAccessed)
        return -1;
    else if (this.domain.equals(arg0.getDomain()))
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

So basically, the map is accessed by the domain name and is sorting according to the timestamp.

I did treemap.get(RobotKey e) where e has the same domain name as an existing entry in treemap but a different timestamp. This should return me the correct RobotValue since the Map operations are done with equals. But it instead returns me null indicating the RobotKey is not found. Any idea why this is happening? What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is about inconsistency of your equals and compareTo methods.
The `compareTo` must return 0 if and only if `equals` returns true, as far as I remember TreeMap (or TreeSet) does not invoke the `equals` method, it just uses `compareTo` and its result to indicate duplicate keys.

Comment: Hi, my compareTo and my equals function are consistent. In both functions, I return 0 or true if the domain names are the same string. But I think you might be right, is there any inconsistency that you see that I missed?

Comment: oh actually i see my problem. return 0 is in my else if statement which may not be invoked if the if is true.

Comment: You have to make it consistent both in terms of `domain` and `lastAccessed`.  Right now, if the domains are different but the `lastAccessed` is equal, you'll return `1`, which is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you override equals you should also override hashCode.

Check out the contract for equals and hashCode in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) which says `If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.`

Your implementation is broken because the map uses hashCode to figure out which bucket the object belongs in, and THEN may use equals to determine if the object is in the bucket or not.  In your case, your two objects which you consider equal generate different hash codes so the collection isn't looking in the same bucket.

Comment: As far as I know TreeMap is not a hash based map

Comment: Yea, I just tried overriding the hashcode function to return to hashcode of hte domain string but this doesn't work.

Comment: I knew it, TreeMap and TreeSet don't invoke `equals` method on objects they contain.

Comment: ah, I didn't look at TreeMap specifically.  In any case, breaking the equals/hashCode contract is bad.  You have a good point in this case and I'll up-vote your answer since it addresses the issue at hand.

Comment: Completely agreed, `equals`, `hashCode` shall be consistent, because who can guarantee that object would never be stored in a HashMap, HashSet? And by the way `equals` and `compareTo` shall be consistent too, because of the same reason about TreeSet and TreeMap.